# How to drop rows of a pyspark dataframe if they're in another dataframe based on the values from two columns?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframe, one with user and item columns, and another with all user item pairs and their scores.
`user| item` and `user | item | item2 | rating2 | score`

I want to remove all the rows from the second table where the user and item appear in the first dataframe.  I can't use subtract since they aren't the same number of columns?

Is this something that could be accomplished with an anti join?

Answer (score 2):

```
df2.join(df1, on=['user', 'item'], how="left_anti")
```

Comment: Answer looks good +1.  You should do a broadcast join if one of the DataFrames is small enough to be broadcasted: `big_df.join(broadcast(small_df)...`.  That'll be a lot faster.